# Rails many to many model, adding records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hello im trying to add some records to my database with this model

```
class Colleagueship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :colleague, :class_name => 'Employee'
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :colleagueships
  has_many :colleagues, :through => :colleagueships
  # ...
end
```

but i have no idea in how to start a new form to create new records
im thinking to try something like

```
def new
  employee = ## gotta get the id here in the form
  @colleagueship = employee.colleagueships.build(:colleague_id => params[:colleague_id])
  @colleagueship.save

end
```

what do you think? how do i achieve this with a post http method? do i have to save the employee variable with the request and add the employee_id there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller

```
def new
end

def create
  # inspect submitted params here
  puts params

  if colleagueship.save
    # etc etc
  else
    # error
  end
end

private

def employee
  @employee = Employee.find_by(params[:employee_id])
end

def colleagueship
  @colleagueship = employee.colleageships.build
end

helper_method :employee, :colleagueship
```

Your routes should be nested to provide the key you'll use to find the employee.

```
resources :employees do
  # this will generate /employees/:employee_id/colleagues/:id
  resources :colleagueships
end
```

In your view, you will probably use the form_tag helper, as it's easier to customize forms with whatever fields you want, especially if you're avoiding accepts_nested_attributes which you should. You can also include a hidden_field_tag with employee_id if you aren't nested your routes.

```
= form_tag new_employee_colleague_path do
  = text_field_tag 'colleageship[name]', placeholder: 'something...'
```

Something along these lines should work. Make sure to inspect the params hash to see that the values are formatted correctly.